# Select doesn't work with flexslider in android (< 4.x)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, flexslider

I seem to face a problem with displaying and selecting the dropdown while using the flexslider in my mobile website. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403439/cant-activate-select-using-flexslider-swipejs-on-android-gingerbread), similar problem was listed. But the solution didn't work for me. I did use useCSS:false, somehow that didn't work for me too. 
I use Android GingerBread.

I can submit buttons, enter text, use checkboxes but just not the dropdown. Any advice is welcome.

==Edited==

I found a somewhat similar reported issue here: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/82
Even if it is a webkit related issue, can anyone suggest any solution for this?

Sometimes the dropdown from other slide is displayed, despite having backface-visibility:hidden.